# Gear keeps falling back to gear 6

Tags: mountain-bike

So basically I fell off my bike and my chain fell of but as soon as I put the chain back on and thought it was perfect I noticed it stayed in gear 6 even if the numbers changed to for example gear 4 it was still on gear 6 so then I put my bike upside down so I could get to the chain easier and then when I put the chain on the gear 5 as soon as I put my hand on the pedal and started pedalling it dropped back into gear 6. What do I do to stop this?

Comment: For a useful answer, we need to know what kind of gear shift you have (deraileur or gear hub?). As a WAG, is 6th gear your smallest sprocket and your gear cable is broken?

Comment: @Alex I have a deraileur

Comment: Did you put the chain on 5th gear by using the shifters or manually moving the chain?

Comment: I put it on chain way because on the shifter it said it was on 5Th but then when I looked at the chain it was on 6th gear so then I put it on by chain and started pedalling and it kept falling back to 6th after several tries I knew there was no point me to keep putting it back on 5th gear if it's going to fall back to 6th gear @Argenti Apparatus

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your derailleur cable broke or got loose and so your derailleur is moving to its default outermost position, the smallest gear (assuming your shifter is labeled such that 6 is the highest gear).

You might be able to find where it's loose and retension it. More likely, you'll need a new derailleur cable. About five to ten Eurodollars.

However, in a situation where your bike toppled, you could have bent your derailleur hanger. It's worth just having the shop do the cable replacement and rear derailleur tuneup and realignment. It should be around half an hour of shop time labor.

Note: another scenario if you have index shifters  is that the crash yanked the derailleur with such force that it broke the index shifter internals such that they do nothing and the derailleur is reverting to default. Again, the shop should be able to tell. New shifters are only fifteen to thirty Eurodollars for the inexpensive lines.